# not number is not updating with firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i'm new at firebase i follow all the guidelines of web firebase auth i manage to login log out and update the all data except the phone number why my phone number is not updating but the console responds  success
here is my code please take a look

```
var confName = 'dharmendra shah'
var confPhone = 7597365803
    var userCreated = auth().currentUser;
              userCreated.updateProfile({
              displayName: confName,
              phoneNumber: confPhone.toString()
             }).then(function () {
           console.log('success');
              Actions.Users();
              }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);[enter image description here][1]
                });
```

In console i got `success message` but it didn't update the phone number and name it does update why is it happen
i'm following this two guidelines
https://rnfirebase.io/ and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

i'm looking this error online but it didn't appear any message

again i'm using createUserWithEmailAndPassword() functionality with react-native ( android ) and the library is rnFirebase
if anyone could help me it will be very generous.

console logs

```
[Fri Apr 24 2020 20:22:58.367]  LOG      {"displayName": null, "email": "dharjejejwjwwjmonly1999@gmail.com", "emailVerified": false, "isAnonymous": false, "metadata": {"creationTime": 1587739956204, "lastSignInTime": 1587739956204}, "phoneNumber": null, "photoURL": null, "providerData": [[Object]], "providerId": "firebase", "uid": "jySTaK4tweYxYQNoXFp3f4qaXQr1"}
[Fri Apr 24 2020 20:22:58.673]  LOG      success
[Fri Apr 24 2020 20:23:04.394]  LOG      {"displayName": "dharmendra shah", "email": "dharjejejwjwwjmonly1999@gmail.com", "emailVerified": false, "isAnonymous": false, "metadata": {"creationTime": 1587739956204, "lastSignInTime": 1587739956204}, "phoneNumber": null, "photoURL": null, "providerData": [[Object]], "providerId": "firebase", "uid": "jySTaK4tweYxYQNoXFp3f4qaXQr1"}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that firebase needs the phone number in a `string` object. Please try to change your number into a string and include country code: `"+525513282913"`

Comment: nope nothing happening!

Answer (score 1):

`updateProfile` only accepts `displayName` and `photoURL`.

You have to use the [`updatePhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatephonenumber) API to update a user's phone number.